# Keeping menus clean when using both KDE and Gnome

Tags: menu

If I want to install KDE alongside Gnome how can I keep KDE apps out of the menu when I am in Gnome and Gnome apps out of the menu when I am in KDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

For Gnome: http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php/Gnome+Menu+Extended+%28Debian+Package%29?content=73515

For KDE: http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=31031

Comment: Although I notice the author is no longer supporting it as he is "no longer a desktop junky"